# Repeated login prompts and being logged in as another user?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, authentication

When visiting the root site, users are repeatedly prompted to login. After many prompts, a partial page will begin to display.

If more than 1 user is attempting to login in the above fashion, another user will suddenly authenticate with minimal or no login and be logged as as another user. It appears to pick up the last user to login, but sometimes picks up a user who has logged out.

The repeated login prompts sometimes locks out our AD accounts.

I have a new SharePoint 2010 instance. There are 2 WFEs (1 was powered off for troubleshooting), 1 CA, 1 index (powered off troubleshooting), 1 SQL, and 1 Apache load-balancing proxy. The issue occurs from our desktops and when remoted into the CA or WFE servers - thus we ruled out the Apache proxy because browsing the site from the CA and WFE server does not hit the proxy.

We start with a fresh SP install and create the SP web application using port 443, a new IIS site, and entering the main, end-user URL in the host header field. We are using NTLM. We don't configure IIS manually. We added a host file entry on the WFE for the IP address of the WFE and the main URL. We added a registry setting on the WFE for the BackConnectionHostNames with the main URL per Article ID: 896861.

The CA site works fine.

We then create a Publishing Portal Site Collection at the root and try to login. There are no other subsites or site collections.